# Custom folders not auto-reloading in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring, docker

In Rails 5 and below, I used to have the following line in `application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/services/**/"]
```

The guides for Rails 6 [state](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths) that "nowadays this is discouraged". So after upgrading to `config.load_defaults 6.0` I deleted these autoload instructions from my config.

Indeed, all my services are found automatically and are loaded during the initial boot sequence. But when I change these files, they are not reloaded.

If I put the above line back into `application.rb`, everything becomes fine again. Since this practice is discouraged, how do I make them auto-reloaded in a Rails 6 way?

Comment: are you using shared volume? or also better to shared Dockerfile

Comment: @Adiii, yes, NFS. Updated the post.

Comment: I tested the app with the `autoload_path` hack, and it works. Clearly, not a Docker issue, right? Updated the post again